# Почему переменная = 0, но код выполняется, хотя в условие написано !=0?

Tags: java, android, if

Никак не могу понять, в чём причина:

```
String name = null;

 public void onClickButton(View view){         //Нажимается кнопка
    name = mAutoComplete.getText().toString();//в переменную помещается  
 }                                             // результат до этого она пустая
 public void onClickPhoto(View view) {// верхняя кнопка появляется после нажатия на эту 
    mAutoComplete.setVisibility(AutoCompleteTextView.VISIBLE);
    button3.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);

    if (name != null) {выполняющийся код}//если переменная не равна 0

 }
```

Но при нажатии на onClickPhoto прога сразу переходит к выполнению кода в фигурных скобках условия, почему она пустая ???

Comment: Попробуй так `if(!Objects.equals(name, null)) {твой код}`

Comment: Врятли в этом дело, но **не надо** назначать слушатели нажатий в разметке - делайте это программно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дело в том, что `mAutoComplete.getText().toString()` возвращает пустую строку если в поле ничего не введено. Нужно делать  либо так

```
String text = mAutoComplete.getText().toString();
if(text.isEmpty()) {
    // какой-то код
}
```

либо так

```
String text = mAutoComplete.getText().toString();
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
    // какой-то код
}
```

Второй вариант безопасней, т.к. он в начале проверяет значение на `null`, а потом на `isEmpty()`